# Chance.js and PHP game scripting

Tags: php, javascript

I'm scripting a small RP game Text base. I found a site with chance.js script free to use but I am trying to find out how to use it within PHP.

This is the code they tell you to use:

```html
<script src="chance.js"></script>
  <script>
     console.log(chance.bool());
  </script>
```

But every time I put it in my PHP it blacks out everything and does not work. I have tried to search everywhere to try and find out why but found nothing. A lot of sites say I can't use JavaScript in PHP, but I know that can't be true.

Please, someone point me in the right direction...   :)

P.S. the replay with be true or false http://chancejs.com/ <<< is the site it's from.

Comment: sorry fixed the wrong tag

Comment: You also need to fix the Java tag next

Comment: It's not that you can't use PHP and JavaScript together, it's that they run in totally different contexts.  PHP runs server side and results (usually) in generating HTML for the browser.  JavaScript runs in the browser totally apart form the server.  If you are adding this in your PHP (like between `<%php %>` tags then it will not compile (because it's not PHP)

Comment: @JasonSperske that is not completely true... the OP could always echo the JS inside the PHP, however, they should be very careful about mixing the two languages together.

Comment: @pattyd if the OP echoed JavaScript it still wouldn't run on the server.

Comment: @JasonSperske he is not trying to run it on the server, he is running it client side through PHP. Right?

Comment: I was trying to address the statement at the end of the question "A lot of sites say I can't use JavaScript in PHP". To PHP a block of JavaScript is the same as a block of HTML, its just output text.

Answer (score 1):

PHP != JavaScript. JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side.

You might want to use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output this into browser do it either as:

```
<?php
...
?>

<script src="chance.js"></script>
  <script>
     console.log(chance.bool());
  </script>

<?php
...
?>
```

or use the **echo** php function:

```
echo '<script src="chance.js"></script>
  <script>
     console.log(chance.bool());
  </script>';
```

Comment: I tried this but all it does is display the code it don't run the script how do i make it run the script?

Answer (score 0):

To echo JavaScript inside of PHP, you should do this:

```
 <?php
 echo"
 <script src='chance.js'></script>
 <script>
 console.log(chance.bool());
 </script>
 ";
 ?>
```

Also, notice that I echoed it inside of double quotes, this means that now if you use double quotes inside of your JS you should escape them like this: `\"`.

As stated in a previous answer, you should be very careful about mixing PHP with JavaScript, as PHP is **always** executed before JS.